# 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' does not contain a definition for 'Center'

Tags: c#, xna

I get this error message in the following line:

```
Point posDiff = new Point(RectF1.Center.X - RectF2.Center.X, RectF1.Center.Y - RectF2.Center.Y);
```

'System.Drawing.RectangleF' does not contain a definition for 'Center' and no extension method 'Center' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is wrong? Which reference is missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply, it's right. Look at the documentation for [`RectangleF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef.aspx). There's no `Center` property. It's not clear why you think there *is* one. Were you getting confused with another type, perhaps?

Of course, it's easy enough to create your own method to return the center of a `RectangleF`, and you could make that an extension method:

```
public static PointF Center(RectangleF rectangle)
{
    return new PointF(rectangle.X + rectangle.Width / 2,
                      rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height / 2);
}
```

It's not clear why you're trying to create a `Point` (`int`-based) from values in a `RectangleF` (`float`-based) though. I could imagine this:

```
PointF center1 = RectF1.Center(); // Using the new extension method
PointF center2 = RectF2.Center();
PointF posDiff = new PointF(center1.X - center2.X, center1.Y - center2.Y);
```

... although I'd be tempted to create a `VectorF` type to make it clear that you're logically talking about the difference between two points, not a new point.

Comment: @Sayse It's "BODMAS".. division before additions :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - I didn't realise c# follows bodmas, my current job doesn't use c# so I fall out of sync with it! (current job language reads left to right)

Comment: @Sayse May I ask what language that is.. ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - SmallTalk... not that many people that use/have heard of it, hence why I use SO to stay in touch with .Net :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28064/discussion-between-sayse-and-simon-whitehead)

Answer (score 2):

As can clearly be seen on the MSDN website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef.aspx

`RectangleF` contains no such member or method or property.

So it literally doesn't exist, what you're doing wrong is trying to use something that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You may have been trying to work through a MAUI graphics example as I was. Try
using RectangleF = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.RectF;